# Dynamic dropdown menu Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu for a button. Preloading the menu from server as json and that part works fine but for some reason bootstrap doesn't display the menu items except for the last in the array.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Select images to view <b class="caret"></b>
    </button>
    <ul ng-repeat="tag in tags" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="view.setTag(tag)">{{tag}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The variable 'tags' contains the preloaded array.

Tried on chrome and IE with the same result.

If I remove the class 'dropdown-menu' from the ul element the complete bullet list will be displayed like:

```
<Button>
foo *
* bar
* baz
```

For info:

The app.js part populating the tags variable:

```
    this.loadTags = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:5566/api/tags').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.tags = data.tags;
        }).
        error();
    }
```

(This works fine however)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem after some experimenting. Moved the ng-repeat to the li element as

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Select images to view <b class="caret"></b>
        </button>
        <ulclass="dropdown-menu">
            <li  ng-repeat="tag in tags"><a href="#" ng-click="view.setTag(tag)">{{tag}}</a></li>
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        </ul>
    </div>
```